# Newer Native Module methods not getting exposed to JS

Tags: android, react-native, npm, cross-platform, react-native-modules

I have an Android native module library project which I have included in another app locally (It's not yet uploaded to npm). Now I have added some more methods to that native module. but those functions are not getting reflected in the JS side. It's saying those methods are `undefined`.

I tried

1. uninstalling and reinstalling the library.
2. Deleting whole node_modules folder and reinstalling
3. Clearing cache with `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Still nothing is working. Other methods which I had added earlier are being exposed to JS. but the new ones are not.